# React Stripe multiple transaction

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I want to implement direct charges to all connected accounts when user fills card information and clicks submit button.
This is Stripe Provider.

```
  <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
  {
    stripePromise && (
    <CheckoutForm
    />
    )
  }

</Elements>
```

and this is called when submit button clicks.

```
  const handleStripeSubmit = async (payment_intents, publishableKey, values) => {

for (const intentItem of payment_intents) {

  const stripeloaded =await loadStripe(publishableKey, {
    stripeAccount: intentItem.stripeAccount
  });

  const loadResult = await stripeloaded.confirmCardPayment(intentItem.clientSecret, {
    payment_method: {
      card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement),
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Jenny Rosen',
      },
    }
  });

  // setStripe(useStripe);
  if (!stripe || !elements) {
    // Stripe.js has not yet loaded.
    // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
    // return;
  }
  const result = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(intentItem.clientSecret, {
    payment_method: {
      card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement),
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Jenny Rosen',
      },
    }
  });
  if (result.error) {
    // Show error to your customer (e.g., insufficient funds)
    window.alert(result.error.message);
  } else if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
    // The payment has been processed!
    window.alert('success');

  }
}
```

React hook value stripe is only indicating Stripe provider loadStripe connect account id.
As loadStripe is a promise, I have tried loadStripe return value but it also gets error.

```
const stripeloaded =await loadStripe(publishableKey, {
    stripeAccount: intentItem.stripeAccount
  });

  const loadResult = await stripeloaded.confirmCardPayment(intentItem.clientSecret, {
    payment_method: {
      card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement),
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Jenny Rosen',
      },
    }
  });
```

Does anyone has a cool idea with batch payment confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to apply payment to multiple connected accounts.
Using multiple direct charge transactions and transfer to connected acccounts.

In multiple transaction, we have to save card information so create a new customer and clone customer to connected accounts (it works.)

Using transfer to connect accounts, please refer stripe seperate and destination charge.